# Making a POST request to google form

Tags: swift, post, nsurlrequest, nsurlsession, google-forms

I would like to make a POST request to a `Google Form` but I'm coming across page not found. I am following [this](http://saa.dfarooq.com/blog/2014/05/24/using-google-spreadsheets-as-database/) guide on using on how to set up the POST request.

I am using this `Google Form`: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1knZJE-3afDGgW9Sqg6Cf6WiMdCSDAkgvi-wc6aRXV3k/viewform

The form has 3 fields and a few hidden input fields such as draftResponse and pagehistory which the tutorial does not mention.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YrQ71fhsX4XQtwV8qHpoHreBeyl1EnNo2pvafsoygtk/edit#gid=990368688")

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

var fieldsToPost = "entry.1959479545=test1&entry.354177126=test2&entry.1807599304=test@gmail.com" as NSString

request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

request.HTTPBody = fieldsToPost.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

    println("Response \(response)")

    var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    println(strData)

    if error == nil {
      println("error")
    }

  })


task.resume()
```

Not sure if my POST information is correct or my implementation. What do you guys think?

Bellow are my `Google Form` page source input fields:

```
input type="text" name="entry.1959479545" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1959479545" dir="auto" aria-label="First Name  " title=""
input type="text" name="entry.354177126" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_354177126" dir="auto" aria-label="Last Name  " title=""
input type="hidden" name="draftResponse" value="[,,&quot;-7091411838997769820&quot;]"
input type="hidden" name="pageHistory" value="0"
input type="hidden" name="fbzx" value="-7091411838997769820"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this task in a utility project I was working on, check it out in this repo: https://github.com/goktugyil/QorumLogs

Here is the tutorial of how to set it up:
https://github.com/goktugyil/QorumLogs/blob/master/Log%20To%20GoogleDocs.md

Heres the code to do it:

```
private static func sendError(#text: String) {
    var url = NSURL(string: formURL)
    var postData = formField1 + "=" + text
    postData += "&" + formField2 + "=" + "anothertext"                
    postData += "&" + formField3 + "=" + "anothertext" 
    postData += "&" + formField4 + "=" + "anothertext" 

    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPBody = postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: nil, startImmediately: true)
}
```

A common mistake is using the "name" field of the input form, however you should use the "id".

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4+**

This is easier to do now with the help of [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

1. View your form source code to get your form URl and the titles for each form field.
2. Create the data variable plugging in the field ID for each item.
3. Submit the code using a simple POST request.

```
let data = ["entry.123123123": suggestedActivities, "entry.123124214": suggestedImprovements]

Alamofire.request(googleFormURL, method: .post, parameters: data).validate()
    .responseString {
        response in
        // do your magic
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**( Swift 5 )**

```
   private func postRequest2(name: String, email: String, phoneNumber: String, note: String){
        var url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/19MbGnGA54cj9nobK5FxvRNcXJ-Gtudb_xSA3VChzSxU/formResponse?entry.631576183=\(name)&entry.922538006=\(email)&entry.836974774=\(phoneNumber)&entry.526236259=\(note)"

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
          guard let data = data else {
            print(String(describing: error))
            return
          }
          print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

working for me
checked: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rYRStyI46L2sjiFF9DTDMlCb2qR2FMtKrZk3USRdXkA/edit#gid=1864592081